# Как убрать некорректную ошибку php?

Tags: php

Код работает, но php выдает ошибку..
Как ее убрать без применения error_reporting

**Текст ошибки:**

> Cannot assign bool to property main\Language::$lang_layout of type array

**Код класса:**

```
class Language
{
    public static array $lang_layout = [];
    public static array $lang_view = [];
    public static function load($code, $view)
    {
        $lang_layout = APP . "/language/{$code}.php";
        $lang_view = APP . "/language/{$code}/{$view['controller']}/{$view['action']}.php";
        if(file_exists($lang_layout)){
          self::$lang_layout =  require_once  $lang_layout;/////РУГАЕТСЯ на эту строку
        }
        if(file_exists($lang_view)){
            self::$lang_view = require_once $lang_view;
        }
        self::$lang_data = array_merge(self::$lang_layout, self::$lang_view);// ТУТ НОРМАЛЬНО ПОЛУЧАЮ ОБА МАССИВА ВМЕСТЕ
    }
    
}
```

Вот файл который подгружается динамически  `APP."/language/{$code}.php"`;
Второй такой же только на другом языке, их всего два возвращают массив

```
<?php
return [
    'tpl_search' => 'Поиск',
    'tpl_login' => 'авторизация',
    'tpl_signup' => 'регистрация',
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С чего вы взяли что ошибка некорректная?

Там все по делу написано

> Cannot assign bool to property main\Language::$lang_layout of type array

Тут написано, что Вы пытаетесь сохранить в свойство `$lang_layout` класса `main\Language` булево значение, несмотря на то,что данное поле содержит массив.
И тут все соответствует действительности.

Строка

```
require_once  $lang_layout;
```

возвращает вам булево значение, потому что вы данный файл уже где-то подключали и вы пытаетесь это сохранить в $lang_layout в котором хранится массив.

Возвращает он вам булево значение а не результат подключения указанного вами файла потому что вы используете не `require`, а `require_once`, который будет вам возвращать `true` если вы уже подключали этот файл.

Поэтому в этом случае вам стоит заменить`require_once` на `require`

```
class Language
{
    public static array $lang_layout = [];
    public static array $lang_view = [];
    public static function load($code, $view)
    {
        $lang_layout = APP . "/language/{$code}.php";
        $lang_view = APP . "/language/{$code}/{$view['controller']}/{$view['action']}.php";
        if(file_exists($lang_layout)){
          self::$lang_layout =  require  $lang_layout;
        }
        if(file_exists($lang_view)){
            self::$lang_view = require $lang_view;
        }
        self::$lang_data = array_merge(self::$lang_layout, self::$lang_view);// ТУТ НОРМАЛЬНО ПОЛУЧАЮ ОБА МАССИВА ВМЕСТЕ
    }    
}
```